# Based on z-score, is it possible to compute confidence without looking at a z-table?

Tags: confidence-interval, z-statistic

How are the values in a z-table computed? Is it possible to compute confidence without looking up a z-table?

Comment: I don't know how to post formulas here, so search google on "normal distribution function" or see, e.g., [here](http://www.rapidtables.com/math/probability/normal_distribution.htm#normal).

Comment: Excel has pretty good functions for the normal distribution, so long as you aren't way out in the tail (where they fall apart).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest answer is that one either uses numerical quadrature techniques (Simpson's, for instance) on the PDF, or approximations such as those found in [Abramowitz and Stegun](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_932.htm). Personally however, since one merely needs a few digits of accuracy for the "error function" that is involved in computing z-scores, you might be interested the simple approximations given [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110719110656/http://homepages.physik.uni-muenchen.de/%7EWinitzki/erf-approx.pdf) by S. Winitzki.

Answer (score 3):

A z-table gives you values of the cumulative distribution function for the standard (i.e., mean = 0, standard deviation = 1) normal distribution. The integral needs to be estimated numerically. See [here for a discussion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function).

Of course, to answer your question literally, you could use some other lookup system other than a table, such as the `pnorm` [function](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Normal.html) in R.
Example:

```
> pnorm(2)
[1] 0.9772499
```

Help for `pnorm` also provides the following reference on how to calculate the cdf of a normal distribution:

- Cody, W. D. (1993) Algorithm 715: SPECFUN – A portable FORTRAN package of special function routines and test drivers. ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software 19, 22–32.

Answer (score 2):

> How are the values in a z-table computed?

You can use more than one methods. You can use the [Simpson's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule) and get an approximate a single individal value in both the positive or negative side of the [standard normal table](https://www.ztable.net). You can also use series approximation or numerical integration.

> Is it possible to compute confidence without looking up a z-table?

You would be more likely to call a function in a package than look up a table. When needed to judge significance of a Z test, a lot of statisticians will know two tailed 20% 10%, 5% & 1% critical values by heart.

Disc: I'm affiliated with the site link above

Comment: +1 Simpson's Rule works well for computing central probabilities.  Mills Ratio works well out in the tails: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7200.  If one has reasonable facility in computing exponentials, both rules are simple enough that they can be applied using mental arithmetic.

Comment: @whuber Fantastic! That's a very informative linked you shared above. Thank you