# Error in normal approximation to a uniform sum distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, moments, approximation

One naive method for approximating a normal distribution is to add together perhaps $100$ IID random variables uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, then recenter and rescale, relying on the Central Limit Theorem. (*Side note*: There are more accurate methods such as the [Box–Muller transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform).) The sum of IID $U(0,1)$ random variables is known as the uniform sum distribution or [Irwin–Hall distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution).

**How large is the error in approximating a uniform sum distribution by a normal distribution?**

Whenever this type of question comes up for approximating the sum of IID random variables, people (including me) bring up the [Berry–Esseen Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem), which is an effective version of the Central Limit Theorem given that the third moment exists:

$$|F_n(x) - \Phi(x)| \le \frac{C \rho}{\sigma^3 \sqrt n} $$

where $F_n$ is the cumulative distribution function for the rescaled sum of $n$ IID random variables, $\rho$ is the absolute third central moment $E|(X-EX)^3|$, $\sigma$ is the standard deviation, and $C$ is an absolute constant which can be taken to be $1$ or even $1/2$.

This is unsatisfactory. It seems to me that the Berry–Esseen estimate is closest to sharp on binomial distributions which are discrete, with the largest error at $0$ for a symmetric binomial distribution. The largest error comes at the largest jump. However, the uniform sum distribution has no jumps.

**Numerical tests suggest that the error shrinks more rapidly than $c/\sqrt n$.**

Using $C=1/2$, the Berry–Esseen estimate is $$|F_n(x) - \Phi(x)| \le \frac{\frac12 \frac{1}{32}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{12}^3} \sqrt n} \approx \frac{0.650}{\sqrt n}$$

which for $n=10,20,40$ is about $0.205$, $0.145$, and $0.103$, respectively. The actual maximum differences for $n=10, 20, 40$ appear to be about $0.00281$, $0.00139$, and $0.000692$, respectively, which are much smaller and appear to fall as $c/n$ instead of $c/\sqrt n$.

Comment: If you expand the distribution of the sum in an [Edgeworth expansion](http://www.amazon.com/Bootstrap-Edgeworth-Expansion-Springer-Statistics/dp/0387945083), you find that $F_n(x)=\Phi(x)+n^{-1}g(x)+o(n^{-1})$ uniformly in $x$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ (since the uniform distribution is symmetric), so $c/n$ sounds about right. Because of the $o(n^{-1})$ term, that doesn't give you a bound though...

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it explains the $c/n$ pattern for many other distributions, too.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let $U_1, U_2,\dots$ be iid $\mathcal U(-b,b)$ random variables and consider the normalized sum
$$
S_n = \frac{\sqrt{3} \sum_{i=1}^n U_i}{b \sqrt{n}} \>,
$$
and the associated $\sup$ norm
$$
\delta_n = \sup_{x\in\mathbb R} |F_n(x) - \Phi(x)| \>,
$$
where $F_n$ is the distribution of $S_n$.

**Lemma 1** (*Uspensky*): The following bound on $\delta_n$ holds.
$$
\delta_n < \frac{1}{7.5 \pi n} + \frac{1}{\pi}\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\right)^n + \frac{12}{\pi^3 n} \exp(-\pi^2 n / 24) \>.
$$

*Proof*. See J. V. Uspensky (1937), *[Introduction to mathematical probability](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000QABFP8)*, New York: McGraw-Hill, p. 305.

This was later improved by R. Sherman to the following.

**Lemma 2** (*Sherman*): The following improvement on the Uspensky bound holds.
$$\delta_n <  \frac{1}{7.5 \pi n} - \left(\frac{\pi}{180}+\frac{1}{7.5\pi n}\right)  e^{-\pi^2 n / 24} + \frac{1}{(n+1)\pi}\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\right)^n + \frac{12}{\pi^3 n} e^{-\pi^2 n / 24} \>.$$

*Proof*: See R. Sherman, [Error of the normal approximation to the sum of N random variables](http://biomet.oxfordjournals.org/content/58/2/396.abstract), *Biometrika*, vol. 58, no. 2, 396–398.

The proof is a pretty straightforward application of the triangle inequality and classical bounds on the [tail of the normal distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13690/how-to-compute-the-probability-associated-with-absurdly-large-z-scores/13809#13809) and on $(\sin x) / x$ applied to the characteristic functions of each of the two distributions.

Comment: +1 Is $N=n$ in Lemma 2?

Comment: @Procrastinator: Good catch.

Comment: Thanks! Those references are very helpful. The estimates seem to be within a factor of $2$ of the actual value.