# standard normal CDF in Excel (by hand)

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function, excel

i'm struggling hard to calculate the CDF in excel without using pre-built formulas.

I have Z score and need to compute CDF of standard Normal distribution.

Let's say i have column A with Z scores 
-3
-2
-1
0
1
2

All i can get is non cumulative distribution using:
=EXP(-1/2*(A2^2))/SQRT(2*PI())

Comment: See Wikipedia on the  [Normal distribution -- Cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) where it says "*These integrals cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions, and are often said to be special functions. However, many numerical approximations are known*". Also see
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168292/closed-form-of-normal-distribution and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18286/why-the-cdf-for-the-normal-distribution-can-not-be-expressed-as-a-closed-form-fu

 ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... and 

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7200/evaluate-definite-interval-of-normal-distribution