# Source code to calculate Cumulative Distribution Function for F-distribution?

Tags: anova, cumulative-distribution-function, f-distribution

I am seeking answers similar to [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7200/evaluate-definite-interval-of-normal-distribution), but for the F distribution rather than the normal distribution.

I seem to have set off alarm bells by asking for source code.  A non-coded answer would also be useful, although there seem to be non-obvious implementation issues such as continued fractions, floating point precision, different algorithms for different input ranges, etc.  Any answer with sufficient explanation to enable a "reduction to practice" would be very much appreciated.  Of course, source code is the most complete and unambiguous answer of all.

My apologies if my question is out of scope of this forum.  I would not want to abuse this valuable resource in any way.

Comment: As for http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/49648/930, I would say this question is off-topic and unlikely to help future visitors interested in statistical science in its theoretical and applied aspects.

Comment: I think this might be better for stackoverflow.

Comment: everything you need is here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution just make it yourself,

Comment: Some remarks: (**1**) Do not be discouraged by the closure of the question. Just because it may be deemed off-topic for this particular site does *not* make it a bad question or a potentially on-topic one at a sister StackExchange site. (cont.)

Comment: (**2**) If $F \sim F(d_1,d_2)$ then $F = d_2 X / (d_1 (1-X))$ where $X \sim \mathrm{B}(d_1/2,d_2/2)$. Note that the transformation is monotonic. So the cdf of an $F$ distribution can always be evaluated via the cdf of a Beta distribution. Indeed, this is precisely how the software `R` goes about it, using the following reference: Didonato, A. and Morris, A., Jr, (1992) Algorithm 708: Significant digit computation of the incomplete beta function ratios, *ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software*, 18, 360–373.

Comment: Cardinal: thank you for the reference.  With your help, I found the  [article](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=131776) and a [Java implementation](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/java_src/toms708/toms708.html)