# Does the normal product distribution have subgaussian tail?

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, random-variable

Consider the [normal product distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalProductDistribution.html), which is the distribution of the product of two or more independent normal variables. Particulary, focus in the case where the multiplied normal variables are $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$.

[image]

Considering the following definition of subgaussian tail (taken from [1]):

[image]

**Does the normal product distribution have subgaussian tail?**

I have been doing some numerical experiments which suggest an affirmative answer ($a=0.1$):

[image]

[1] Matoušek, J. (2008). On variants of the Johnson–Lindenstrauss lemma. Random Structures & Algorithms, 33(2), 142-156.

Comment: +1.  I think this may be easy to resolve by comparing the event $XY\gt \lambda$ to the event $\min(X,Y)\gt \sqrt{\lambda}.$  It may help to know [Mills' Ratio](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/7206/919).

Comment: Re your experiments: these plots don't provide any information about subgaussianity because they don't have the resolution to let you see it.  Use a probability plot of the simulated data instead.  As an example, here's an exponential probability plot for simulated data in `R`: `n <- 1e4; plot(-log(1-ppoints(n)), sort(abs(rnorm(n) * rnorm(n))))`.

Comment: the product of two iid standard Gaussians is not subgaussian: see e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804093/product-of-sub-gaussian-rvs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the case of the product of two independent standard Gaussian r.v's $X,Y$: $Z=XY$. Then, one can easily compute the MGF of $Z$:
$$
\forall |\theta|<1,\qquad \mathbb{E}[e^{\theta Z}]
= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[e^{\theta XY}\mid X]] = \mathbb{E}[e^{\frac{\theta^2}{2}X^2}] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\theta^2}}
$$
the last equality since $X^2$ is distributed as a [chi-squared r.v.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution). In particular, the MGF of $Z$ is **not** defined for all of $\mathbb{R}$. But $\mathbb{E}[Z]=0$, so sub-gaussianity of $Z$ would be equivalent to its MGF being defined for all $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ and satisfying
$$
\phi(\theta) \leq e^{K\theta^2}
$$
for some absolute constant $K>0$ (see e.g. [this book](https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.html#), Proposition 2.5.2). Clearly, it does not.

Comment: (Note that however it is a **sub-exponential** r.v., as the product of two sub-gaussian r.v.'s is always subexponential.)