# Hypothesis Test for a Proportion. Z-score = -44

Tags: hypothesis-testing, z-score

I got $n = 8000$, and I get a z-score of $-44$. 
How do I deal with this? How do I find the probability if I can't look this up in the Z-table?

Comment: You can approximate it easily: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7200/evaluate-definite-interval-of-normal-distribution/7206#7206.  You can also calculate it with suitable software.  For instance, *Mathematica* gives the (one-sided) p-value as $3.6322\ldots \times 10^{-423}.$  That's an indication you shouldn't sweat this detail: it's an astronomically small number.

Answer (score 1):

Convention dictates that you specify your p-value is less than the lowest value on your z-table. 
Suppose the lowest probability on your z-table is $0.001$, then you should say $p<0.001$.

All statistical software employs this method, with varying thresholds.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to refer the observed Z to a normal distribution, to a very good approximation $P(Z\le -44)=0$. So you could just report the p-value as approximately zero.